# mysql LIKE condition in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In my database I store a users permission in "binary" format I have 3 users permsissions, Admin, Manager, Finance. Theses are represent by a short "binary" string,

```
Admin - 100
Manager - 010
Finance - 001
```

Now the roles are interchangable and a user can have more than one role for example a user can have finance and manager permissions, represented like this, "011" basically 1 represents on 0 represents off.

My problem is looking for data in my Laravel relationships, currently I am doing the following, to find a manager.

```
public function managers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->wherePivot('role', '=', '010')->withPivot(['created_at' => 'created_at as joined', 'role' => 'role as role']);
}
```

Now obviously this only works if the user is a manager and not a finance aswell. I figure I could use mysql's `LIKE` to compare the permission to string, but I can work out to look for partial matches?

For example how would I check the second of three is either 0 or 1? Simple rule is,

First number = 1 then owner permission,
Second Number = 1 then manager permission,
Thirder number = 1 then finance permission

but there can be any number of combinations.

Comment: Isn't there a SUBST or CHARAT function you could use for that?

Comment: `wherePivot('role', 'LIKE', '_1_')`

Comment: Seems like you could avoid this problem by creating a permissions table and having a many to many relationship between users and permissions.

Comment: I did think about but I would have `Organisations n:n Users` & `Users n:n Permission` meaning I would need to pivot of a pivot to get the functionality I need?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that would be the case. I can't remember if I've tried that before, but I think it seems like it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`substring`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to do this. Like so:

```
$this->belongsToMany('User')
     ->wherePivot(DB::Raw('SUBSTRING(role, 2, 1)'), '=', '1');
```